# Насмерть vs вусмерть

Tags: выбор-слова

Насмерть or вусмерть, when do I use what?

Comment: That is really short for proper question. You should always supply some examples.

Answer (score 13):

Those words have quite different domains of usage. In fact, any time you are talking about death, death literally, it's "насмерть" - `разбиться насмерть`. Also, when you are talking about extreme level of something, than in most cases it is "насмерть" as well: `они стояли насмерть за свою родину`, `слушай, дверь насмерть просто закрылась, никак не открыть`.

"Вусмерть" in modern Russian is about extreme states of conscience, about being at the edge of functioning. `Напиться вусмерть` - is to drink way to much, bit that does not imply death. In fact, "вусмерть" is used mostly in drunk-related context.

There are, though, some cases when those two words are interchangeable. `Я просто вусмерть с ними рассорился`/`я прям насмерть на него обиделся`.

In short, to non-native speaker who is yet to gain some experience in de-facto word usage I'de recommend to use "вусмерть" about being drunk (or stoned) and "насмерть" in other cases. This is oversimplification but it's something worth to start with.

Comment: "Вусмерть" is highly informal, and considerably rare. Are the verbs "рассориться" and "обидеться" interchangeable?

Comment: @bipll between sentences, no they are not. Sentences them selfs are kind equal, as use case, but describes different aspects of situation as process and such. Are  вусмерть/насмерть interchangeable in these sentences - yes, that is good valid example.

Answer (score -5):

Вусмурть - I hear this word first time. I'm russian btw. I may say that for sure this word is out of date and you won't find nowadays, only in old books maybe.

Comment: если вы не напивались вусмерть, это ещё не значит, что слово не существует) ваш ответ вводит в заблуждение

Comment: @FlaminCat, maybe it just isn't used in some specific region?

Comment: @Roux it's know widely enough at least, although it may sound like grandma word for someone. Probably FlaminCat is young enough not to know.